# On Click event for a button in custom dialog in android

Tags: java, android, customdialog

I am using an custom dialog and i want to get the click of the button, and nothing is happening when the button is clicked. Please have a look at it.

```
public class custom_dialog extends Dialog {
    Context m_context;
    public custom_dialog (Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.m_context = context;
    }

    public custom_dialog (Context context, int theme) {
        super(context,theme);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.m_context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.blue0:
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hii..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i get in logcat.

```
06-01 23:41:14.062    1512-1543/?                              I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to current input target
06-01 23:41:14.062    1512-1543/?                              I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to current input target
06-01 23:41:14.062    1512-1543/?                              I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to current input target
06-01 23:41:14.250    1512-1544/?                              I/InputReader: dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
06-01 23:41:14.250    1512-1543/?                              I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to current input target
06-01 23:41:14.328    2954-2954/com.aavishkaar.quickies        W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
06-01 23:41:14.351    2954-2954/com.aavishkaar.quickies        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.aavishkaar.quickies.MainActivity$custom_dialog.onCreate(MainActivity.java:238)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
        at com.aavishkaar.quickies.MainActivity.button1(MainActivity.java:96)
        ... 14 more
06-01 23:41:14.359   1512-10029/?                              E/liblog: failed to call dumpstate
06-01 23:41:14.359    1512-1524/?                              E/: Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
06-01 23:41:14.359   1512-10029/?                              D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
06-01 23:41:16.531    1512-1536/?                              D/BatteryService: update start
06-01 23:41:16.937    1566-1566/?                              E/StatusBarPolicy: ecio: 19
06-01 23:41:16.937    1566-1566/?                              E/StatusBarPolicy: iconLevel: 4
```

This is the button event which calls the custom dialog.

```
  public void button1(View view)
  {
     final custom_dialog dialog = new custom_dialog(this,R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.dimAmount = 0.1f;

    dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);


  // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
awesomePager = (ViewPager)dialog. findViewById(R.id.pager);
 awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
  dialog.show();
```

}

Comment: case R.id.blue0:?? why is this?

Comment: did you provide a View with a Button to your custom Dialog?

Comment: did you set the button's onClickListener?

Comment: blue0 refers to the button in xml, it is the id.

Comment: how do i setup onClickListener? i thought onClick was enough. Ya, i have provided the view, I am able to see my dialog on my cell, but when i click, i don't get any response.

Comment: The exception only comes when i extend and implement onClickListener to the custom dialog class

Comment: whats at `com.aavishkaar.quickies.MainActivity$custom_dialog.onCreate(MainActivity.java:238)`, says there is a `NullPointerExecption`, meaning something you  are trying to use is `NULL` (usually means you have not set it) update your code to show use what you have

Comment: I managed to sort out the problem, i use a viewpager in the dialog which uses 2 xml in them. I was referring to the button in one of the xml in the viewpager. How do i refer to that button in the viewpager??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class custom_dialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        findViewById(R.id.blue0).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}
```

your custom_dialog has to implement OnClickListener and you have to set "this" as click listener for your button

Comment: Adding your code gets an exception when i run it on my cell. The custom dialog does not appear only.. Previously it used to.

Comment: I mean the app just hangs.. when the custom dialog is launched.

Comment: what does "hangs" mean? Does it crash?

Comment: Provide the logcat showing the exception that causes the crash (update your question with it).

Comment: check my edit. You have to call setContentView with your layout you want to set in your dialog

Comment: I have set the contentView as you said, but i still get the same error, i have updated my question with the logcat results, please have a look.

Comment: The exception only comes when i extend and implement onClickListener to the custom dialog class

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the buttons `onClickListener` in the `onCreate` methody

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.blue0); 
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and implement the `View.onClickListener` on the class

Comment: Adding your solution gives an error to my code in myButton.setOnClickListener(this);  should i implement onClickListener along with this class and your code??

Comment: yes you have to implement the View.onClickListener on the dialog class

Comment: Then my app crashes when i try to open the custom dialog.

Comment: add the `setContentView` like blackbelt mentions in the comment on the other answer

Comment: Still the same result, even after adding it. I had added in the code i called the object.